# Can quorum public network use https?

Tags: quorum

Can quorum public network use https ?
I want to hide data from other than consensus participants, and I don't want to use private transactions.

Comment: what do you mean hide data within the quorum network. You can always encrypt the data u save in smart contracts. But if the quorum client doesn't support ssl/tls, you won't able to use it, as the nodes need to read the data u send to them.

Comment: I am sorry for my poor english. I just want to encrypt p2p consensus communication.

Comment: i don't know if quorum does allow that, but if you know the go lang you could add that yourself.